# (./runalg: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token 'set' )in Middle bury evaluation

Tags: cygwin, stereo-3d

I am testing stereo algorithm in MiddleBury evaluation. I am using cygwin in Windows to run the program.

After compiling tools, I have run the code. According to the guide, I need to write as follows"

> ./runalg

But it says:

> $ ./runalg
>   -bash: ./runalg: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

So, I have changed like

> bash ./runalg.

In this case, the error was as follows.

> $ bash ./runalg
>
> ./runalg: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `set'
>
> ./runalg: line 25: `if ($#argv > 3) set suffix = $4'**

Is there anyone, who can advice me how to use this evaluation and why this problem was occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csh and bash/ksh-type shells have a totally different syntax. Except for very simple commands, you won't be able to get compatibility just by changing the interpreter.

If you had bash script and ksh interpreter, a few adaptations could make the script work in most cases but here no way!

ex in csh:

```
set suffix = $4
```

would translate to

```
suffix=$4
```

(or maybe `export suffix=$4` I don't know the exact variables propagations in csh but that's not the point)

The best way is to actually install `csh` in Cygwin.

According to [this forum](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110907121431AALbDWq), the C Shell is not installed by default in Cygwin. Startup the Setup program and select the "Shells" collection of packages and select csh for installation.

Comment: Thank you. It was solved after installing csh in cygwin

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me a few hours at least.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad this is useful for some! It's basic knowledge but only for the people who know what the problem is :)